# how to fix sql.sql error I do not haved the library?

Tags: python

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys
base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname('bot_grabber.py'), '..'))
sys.path.append(base_dir)
from sql.sql import SQL

api_id = os.getenv('API_ID')
api_hash = os.getenv('API_HASH')

app = Client('bot_python', api_id, api_hash)
bd = SQL('../bd.db')
```

> from sql.sql import SQL
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sql.sql'

Reviewed a lot of information, and I can not understand what is here. write how to fix

Answer (score 0):

did you need to install SQL?

```
pip install sql


import sql
db = sql.SQL(connection)
```

https://pypi.org/project/sql/

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable